# Ansible AWS dynamic inventory instance filters not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I've setup Amazon's dynamic inventory for Ansible according to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/.  I'm able to get an inventory of every EC2 instance on this account but I'd like to filter that down using tags.  I've set `instance_filters` in my ec2.ini but the script still returns the entire inventory.

```
instance_filters = tag:environment=qa
```

```
ansible all -i ec2.py -m ping
```

I also made sure the environment variable to point to ec2.ini was set.

```
export EC2_INI_PATH=/path/to/ec2.ini/its/different/on/my/machine/I/swear
```

What steps/configs am I missing that actually filters EC2 instances?

Comment: Please show how EC2 instances are tagged just in case?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know what `aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag,Values=environment=qa` has to say, since it's possible you are expecting a shorter list than is really coming back. You can also just run that inventory manually to ensure you and it are on the same page `EC2_INI_PATH=whatever python ./ec2.py --list`

Comment: Maybe you're using a different version of the `aws` utility but I had to use this syntax: `aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:environment,Values=qa`

Answer (score 0):

The `instance_filters` config was working as expected.  The problem was that the extra "hosts" I was picking up were actually ElasiCache clusters.  In order to exclude those from inventory I had to add the config below to ec2.ini.

```
elasticache = False
```